# How to set div widths to be max width of divs

Tags: jquery, css

I have div elements that I am setting their length & width like so :

```
<div id="alldivs" style="width:600px;">
    <div id="div1" class="mydiv" style="float: left; min-width:140px; max-width:185px;">
        test text
    </div>
    <div id="div2" class="mydiv" style="float: left; min-width:140px; max-width:185px;">
        test text 2
    </div>
</div>
```

How can the width of each div element within `#alldivs` be set to the max width? So in above example width of `#div2` will be set to width of `#div1` as `#div2` contains more text and therefore will have a greater width. I guess I could use jQuery to iterate the div elements to find the largest width element and then set each div accordingly but perhaps there is a cleaner method using CSS, or even jQuery using a more elegant method?

Comment: Set the max-width on `alldivs` then use `width:100%` on the inner divs?

Comment: @shnisaka by this you mean 'impossible' ?

Answer (score 0):

What if you were to simply put all of the divs in a #divWrapper div and apply your min max widths to that div. That way they should all just inherit from above. Simple. Easy. Clean.

Comment: ok but the width is determined by the amount of text that the div contains, so this will be different for each div.

Comment: Which is why if you put the min/max width declaration on the outer div instead of the inner div, whichever div has the most stuff inside it (the largest width) will push out the wrapper div allowing all of the other divs to fill up an equal amount of space that doesn't exceed that of the widest div.

Comment: ive updated the question, the outer div width is already set cannot use your solution. Apologies for just adding this now.

Comment: You could still throw another div inbetween the two layers.

Answer (score 0):

CSS developers did not concentrate on that but hopefully in the future they will do if you report this to major browsers. Currently you can only do this with `jQuery` as you have mentioned. I do not think you will find any cleaner way to do it so stick with `jQuery`. That is all I can say about it. I had this problem before and I could not find a solution for it. So what I did, instead of using `jQuery`, I specified my `div`'s with a specific width and abandoned using the `max-width`. Hope that helped.

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721136/full-screen-background-html) maybe this will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the two inner divs to be 180px then in your CSS you would use

```
#alldivs div{width:180px;}
```

Or perhaps I read your question wrong?

Here is a jsFiddle that illustrates the above,..

http://jsfiddle.net/nabhW/

Comment: I want each div to be ov equal length, so if one div has enough text which causes it to have a greater width I want all other divs to the same width as this div. So every div contains the same width min-width which is equal to the max-width of all the divs.