# css full width background with content div, wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, html, background, width

I am using a wordpress theme for my portfolio site and I am trying to recreate an effect that I see many sites using now.  Its essentially a full width background image or css background color with standard page width content.

Here is an example: http://themeforest.net/item/vernumresponsive-onepage-parallax-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/4843905

When you go about half way down the page you will see the "Are you ready to buy this theme" section.  Its like a page break with content.  I want to do that in wordpress, but I don't need to have the parallax effect.  I just need the image background or background color css to break the initial content container, but keep the content inside it confined to that container.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721136/full-screen-background-html

Answer (score 0):

You can use shortcode in your theme.

#### Example :

in your theme :

```
function fullWidthBreak_func( $atts ){<br/>
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
'content' => 'default content'
), $atts ) );
return "some css to full widht : $content";<br/>
}<br/>
add_shortcode( 'fullWidthBreak', 'fullWidthBreak_func' );
```

in your post:

```
some content before<br/>
[fullWidthBreak content="some content inside"]
some content after<br/>
```

#### Reference :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Your code snippet didn't work for me.  I added it to the function.php file but I may have entered it incorrectly.  But it breaks the theme I am currently using.