# css background image that auto scales and crops to fill screen

Tags: css, background

Is there a CSS rule that will automatically scale an image and crop it to fill an entire container?

So let's say the width-to-height ratio of an image is greater than the width-to-height ratio of the container.  In this case, the image height should match the height of the container, causing the extra space on the left and right of the image to crop.  If the width-to-height ratio of an image is less than the width-to-height ratio of the container, then the width of the image should match the width of the container, causing the extra space at the top and bottom of the image to crop.

Right now, i'm using javascript to do all these calculations and scaling.

Is there a CSS rule that can do this for me?

Comment: [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: i remember trying background-size:100% 100%, and it distored the image, such that it didn't respect the aspect ratio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [full screen background html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721136/full-screen-background-html)

Comment: Syntax is documented at the link provided by kalley. See use of the "cover" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the following CSS3 rule

`background-size:cover`